# Country Names of the world Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking for a gem or just the data for countries of the world. I only want the names though, no shortcode i.e US/UK. options i have looked at are a bit overkill for my needs. Does anyone know of such a gem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use the gem of geocoder is very powerful y easy of user http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

use <%= select("venue", :country , Country.all.collect {|c| [ c[0] , c[1] ] }, {:include_blank => ' '}) %>

for create a select

Answer (score 0):

Found it, this fits my requirements

gem "terrarum"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this list](http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/countries_of_the_world.htm) is what you need? Short and simple.